# Копирование файлов с использованием cp и rsync

Tags: linux, link, rsync

### **Копирование с cp**

[image: Копирование с cp]

### **Копирование с rsync**

[image: Копирование с rsync]

**Первый скрин:** Почему cp делает из ссылки папку? Как это исправить с cp?

**Второй скрин:** rsync скопировал так как я ожидал. Стоит ли всегда использовать rsync вместо cp?

Comment: Какую задачу вы решаете?

Comment: @dbg, вопросы под скриншотами

Comment: По сути Вы указали `cp` оглавление (а не его содержимое, что видимо желали (`cp -R test1/link_to_1/* test2/link_to_1`) ), вот и скопировали его (рекурсивно) в `test2/1`.

Comment: Кстати, странный у Вас скриншот. Такой результат должен получаться для `cp -RL ... ...` (-L заставляет cp "раскрывать линки"). В Вашем случае `cp -R ... ...` в `test2/1` должен был скопироваться именно символьный линк `link_to_1`, указывающий на имя `1`. Проверьте еще раз.

Comment: @avp, `cp -R test1/link_to_1 test2/link_to_1/` - копируется ссылка;

`cp -R test1/link_to_1/ test2/link_to_1/` - ссылка превращается в папку;
`cp -R test1/link_to_1/* test2/link_to_1/` - копируется содержимое source;

Comment: Да, с завершающим source слэшем Вы правы (не обратил внимания). `Почему cp делает из ссылки папку?` -- а что еще она может сделать?

Comment: @avp но ведь она должна скопировать содержимое папки на которую ссылается link

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43609/discussion-between--and-avp).